# Can u prove this nice equality i found?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I have just seen new Michael Penn video "a general integral family". He showed that (for all $a \geq 1, \, b \geq a$) holds
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{+\infty}{\cfrac{x^{a-1}}{1+x^b} \, \mbox dx} = \cfrac{\pi}{b \, \sin \left( \cfrac{a\pi}{b}\right)}
\end{equation}
In the video he used a nice trick in ordier to evaluate this integral, i link the video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n05P-PgQkWQ

I tried it on my own before watchinng the video. First of all I split the integral into $\int_0^1 + \int_1^\infty$ and use the substitution $x = \cfrac{1}{t}$ in the second one. This lead me to the integral

\begin{equation}
\int_0^{1}{\cfrac{x^{a-1} + x^{b-a-1}}{1+x^b} \, dx}.
\end{equation}

Now i thought i can write $\cfrac{1}{1+x^b}$ as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty{(-x^b)^n} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty{(-1)^n \, x^{nb}}$.

It follows that

\begin{align}
\int_0^{1}{\cfrac{x^{a-1} + x^{b-a-1}}{1+x^b} \, dx} &= \int_0^{1}{ \sum_{n=0}^\infty{(-1)^n \, x^{nb}} \{x^{a-1} + x^{b-a-1} \} \, dx} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty{(-1)^n} \int_0^{1} {x^{nb+a-1} + x^{(n+1)b-a-1} dx} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty{(-1)^n} { \left [ \cfrac{x^{nb+a}}{nb+a} + \cfrac{x^{(n+1)b-a}}{(n+1)b-a} \right ]_0^1 }
\end{align}

Thanx to the condition on $a$ and $b$, this lead me to prove that

\begin{equation}
\int_0^{+\infty}{\cfrac{x^{a-1}}{1+x^b} \, dx} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} {(-1)^n \left\{ \cfrac{1}{nb+a} + \cfrac{1}{(n+1)b-a} \right\}}
\end{equation}

Finally, using Michael Penn result I achieved that

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} {(-1)^n \left\{ \cfrac{1}{nb+a} + \cfrac{1}{(n+1)b-a} \right\}} = \cfrac{\pi}{b \, \sin \left( \cfrac{a\pi}{b}\right)}
\end{equation}

I am not really into series but i think this is a nice result.
Can someone prove this equality not using this integral but other series tools?

Thx everyone

Comment: Ramanujan's master theorem should also work.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem

Answer (score 2):

**Beta function**

Convert the integral into a Beta function by the substitution: $x=\tan^{\frac{2}{b}}\theta  $ as

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x^b} d x& =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\tan ^{\frac{2(a-1)}{b}} \theta}{\sec ^2 \theta} \cdot \frac{2}{b} \tan ^{\frac{2}{b}-1} \theta \sec ^2 \theta d \theta \\
& =\frac{2}{b} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \tan ^{\frac{2 a}{b}-1} \theta d \theta \\
& =\frac{2}{b} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^{\frac{2 a}{b}-1} \theta \cos ^{-\frac{2 a}{b}+1} \theta d \theta \\
& =\frac{1}{b} B\left(\frac{a}{b},-\frac{a}{b}+1\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
By the reflection property of Beta function: $$
B(x, 1-x)=\pi \csc(\pi x) \quad x\not \in\mathbb{Z},
$$
we have
$$\boxed{\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x^b} d x = \frac{\pi}{b \sin \left(\frac{a \pi}{b}\right)} }$$

Comment: I think the OP was asking for a direct proof of the last equality involving a series, not the integral.